# Buffer by field value in the processing modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-modeler, qgsexpression

I am using the processing modeler in QGIS 3.10. I want to buffer polygons by individual field attributes. This is not a problem when I am **not** using the processing modeller since one can simply choose the respective attribute field from the loaded layers. However, when I want to automize the workflow in the processing modller, I don't know how to tell QGIS from where it should take the attributes since there are nor preloaded layers in the processing modeller (see picture attached). I guess, I have to use the "Expression string builder", but I don't know which command I should use. Let's assume layer x contains the field y, which has the respective attributes values I want to use for buffering (which differ by polygon, so it's not a constant value). Any Ideas how I express that in the "Expression string builder", when using the processing modeler?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the "normal" Buffer-Tool, use `variable distance buffer`-Tool:

Add a `Vector Field Input` and change the input of the tool to `Model Input`. Then choose your field.

[image]

So your model looks something like this (simplified):

[image]